# How to avoid caching in IE with REST Api?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, http

We have a REST api which works in Chrome but we found that cached results are used in IE.

In order to fix customers have to go to internet options and change the setting 'Check for the newer version of stored pages" to 'Every time I visit the web page'.

I have seen that I could put at datetime at the end of each of my requests using javascript like so

```
 /v1/getInfo?Date = (new Date())
```

However this means I have to tell all the customers to do this.

Is there a better way of doing this so that my requests look like

```
 /v1/getInfo
```

without changing the URL?

Comment: You can add HTTP headers to instruct the browser not to cache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check what headers your API is returning. In particular check the configuration of Expires and Cache-Control headers. Those are what inform browsers/clients to store a local copy of the message body and to use that next time they request the same resource.

Comment: If you can review what headers are being returned in your browser's console, I may be able to tell you which ones are causing the problem, and what they need to be changed to.

Comment: I see a Response key header of value 'Http/1.1 304 Not Modified' but the corresponding request has no no 'IF-Modified-Since' or 'ETag' headers, which I thought would have resulted in a 304. Request headers are: Key Value
Request GET /v1/test/data HTTP/1.1
Authorization Basic dXNlcjo=
Accept application/json, text/plain, */*
Session 1472A39E6B9476442C296BD168E121F
Referer http://192.21.23.11/
Accept-Language en-US
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko

Comment: Interesting. And no "If-None-Match" header in the request, either?

Comment: We definitely need to get your server to always return 200 OK, not 304 Not Modified, whenever the response has indeed changed. That is the problem right there.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no control of the server side code :(. There is no 'If-Non-Match' header set which is very confusing. It must be using some algorithm under the hood.

Comment: You know, in this scenario, if the server-side application is not your responsibility, I think your original suggestion of recommending your users to provide the current timestamp in a query parameter to bypass local caches, is a perfectly good solution. It requires a change in server-side configuration, really, but if that's not a possibility this is probably the best workaround. :)

Comment: Thanks Kieran for all your help. It looks like I will go with your solution in addition to your last comment.

Answer (score 4):

For this task, you should set up the correct HTTP Headers in your application. The caching is controlled by the `Cache-Control` header:

```
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

Though in itself, this is not bulletproof, so you may need to set up other headers too. This [guide](http://www.mobify.com/blog/beginners-guide-to-http-cache-headers/) seems like a nice writeup.